# How to get list of custom annotations declared in class

Tags: java, reflection

I have created custom annotations to get the list of classes which are having these markers on runtime (Working as expected).

```
import java.lang.annotation.ElementType;
import java.lang.annotation.Retention;
import java.lang.annotation.RetentionPolicy;
import java.lang.annotation.Target;

@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Target(ElementType.TYPE)
public @interface Marker {
  @interface Only{}
  @interface Marker1{}
  @interface Marker2{}
}
```

I need a mechanism to get the list of the markers declared in these test classes. Below is the code which I am trying to run to get these, but no luck!!

```
@Marker.Only
public class Sample {

    @Test
    public void main() {
        Assert.assertTrue(true);
    }

    @AfterMethod
    public void m2(ITestResult result) {
        Annotation[] acc = result.getMethod().getRealClass().getAnnotations();
        // Getting blank array as acc
        System.out.println(acc);
    }
}
```

Comment: Your annotation appears to be on the class, not the method however you are accessing the method for some reason. You can try result.class.getDeclaredAnnotations()

Comment: @AniAggarwal getRealClass() returns the Sample.class and getAnnotations is callled on same. this.getClass().getAnnotations() is also not working.

Comment: I wonder if it has anything to do with retention policy on the Only interface since that's the annotation you have on. By default the retention policy is class maybe that is causing this. I don't think the retention policy on the Marker class will apply for the sub classes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You declare a top-level type `@Marker` that has `RUNTIME` retention, but then you declare several nested types (atypical for annotations, by the way), each of which has *no retention policy*, therefore defaulting to `CLASS`. Apply the retention policy to each of your annotation types.